# Kivy : How to manage different viewports

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am trying to build a game on Kivy that will be working on desktop and on mobile. I am really confused by how i should manage different window sizes, if i set a fixed size on my widgets.

How would someone go to design a game so that every element is "responsive" to screen size, with a similar rendering on all of the devices?

Can you point me to some Kivy api reference, or give me some code samples to learn from?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about things like pixel art, but for standard widgets like buttons and such you can use relative sizing with a `FloatLayout`. You give `size_hint`s that basically say "I want my widget to take up 10% of the height of my screen and 100% of the width" and it will do that no matter the screen size.